# MySQL In clause not giving the right result

Tags: mysql, sql

In a  MySQL table i have a field, containing this value for a given record : "1908,2315,2316"

Here is my sql Query :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 2316 IN (myfield)
```

I got 0 results!

I tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 2315 IN (myfield)
```

Still 0 results

And then i tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1908 IN (myfield)
```

Surprisingly i obtained the record when searching with 1908! What should i do to also obtain the record when searching with 2315 and 2316 ? What am i missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the list of [MySQL string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html).

Comment: Storing comma separated lists in a column is all-too-familiar SQL Antipattern. See Bill Karwin's book: [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be storing comma delimited values in a field.  This is bad, bad, bad.  You should be using a junction table, with one row per value.

But, sometimes you are stuck with data in a particular structure.  If so, MySQL provides the `find_in_set()` functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE find_in_set(2316, myfield) > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IN()` over comma separated list of no.s its better  to normalize your structure first for now you can use `find_in_set` to find results matching with comma separated string

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE find_in_set('1908',myfield) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked and answered before, but I don't want to hunt for it; this question should be closed as a duplicate. But, to answer your question:

The *commas* in the string, the column value, are just *characters*. Those are part of the string. They aren't seen as "separators" between values in the SQL text. The way SQL sees it, the column contains a *single* value, not a "list" of values.

So, in your query, the `IN (field)` is equivalent to an *equals* comparison. It's equivalent to comparing to a string. For example:

```
... WHERE 2316 = '1908,2315,2316'
```

And those aren't equal, so the row isn't returned. The "surprisingly" finding of a match, in the case of:

```
... WHERE 1908 IN ('1908,2315,2316')
```

that's explained because that string is being evaluated in a *numeric* context. That is, the comparison returns true, because all of these also true:

```
... WHERE 1908 = '1908,2315,2316' + 0
... WHERE 1908 = '1908xyz' + 0
... WHERE 1908 = '1907qrs' + 1
```

(When evaluated in a numeric context, a string gets converted to numeric. It just happens that the string evaluates to a numeric value that equals the integer value it's being comparing to.)

---

You may be able to make use of the MySQL **`FIND_IN_SET`** function. For example:

```
... WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2316,'1908,2315,2316')
```

---

But, please seriously reconsider the design of storing comma separated list. I recommend Bill Karwin's "SQL Antipatterns" book...

[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557)

Answer (score 0):

In mysql `IN` clause is utilized as

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column_name IN (set_of_values) ;
```

Mention column name instead of values

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT (',', 2316 ','), CONCAT (',',myfield,',' ) ) <>0
```